# Is it safe to reuse Fragment after onDestroy() has been called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am using the `Fragment` class with the Android support library v7. In my `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method I create a bunch of fragments and store them into properties of my activity.

```
this.firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
this.secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
// and so on
```

I use the navigation drawer pattern to switch between the fragments of my app. To change the active fragment I use following code.

```
// Replace the current content of the fragment holder with the selected section fragment.
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, selectedFragment).commit();
```

This results in a call to `onDestroy()` of the removed fragment. Is it safe to reuse the fragment after it's `onDestroy()` has been called, or should I recreate the fragment every time it is shown to the user.

This is a question of time vs. memory consumption, as at least one of the fragments needs some time to get created.

Comment: As long as you are still using your fragment, your onDestory will not be called. It only gets called once the activity managing the fragment has been destroyed.

Comment: The activity is not destroyed (`onDestroy()` is not called). Only `onDestroy()` on my fragment is called. Can anybody confirm this behavior, so we can eliminate I am doing something wrong?

Also, the description of the fragment lifecycle of the developer guide hints that onDestroy() should be called even when the activity is running ("The lifecycle of a fragment (while its activity is running)").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onDestroy` functionality is to destroy all the used variables and consumed memory. All those will be flagged as a Dummy data to enable the `garbage collector` to remove them from the memory whenever it is needed.

Calling the `Fragment` again after calling `onDestroy` will pass through the lifecycle again from the beginning through `onCreate` and all the `variables` and local `object` will be re-initialized again.

**Is it Safe?** Yes, it is safe.

You are thinking deeper to handle the [lifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) of the `Fragment` that is already being handled by the OS.

If you want to prevent the `Fragment` from being destroyed you can create it as a `static` object.

Comment: I am fine with this answer, plus the tip with making the fragment static is a good solution to my current problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Fragments developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) seems to tell no, according to the lifecycle diagram.

If you want to keep your fragment for a later use, i suggest you use `FragmentTransaction.detach(Fragment)` or `FragmentTransaction.hide(Fragment)` instead of `FragmentTransaction.remove(Fragment)`.